# How to cache IFileProvider response for all users in ASP.NET Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI that services other apps with images. The incoming request can dictate the max-height of an image using query string.

So if an app wants a specific image with max-width of 200px, the request would be `https://example.com/images/blue_skye.jpg?maxwidth=200` and if the app wants the image in the original size the request would then be `https://example.com/images/blue_skye.jpg`.

My WebApi creates various image sizes on the fly for each request. I want to be able to cache the server response in the memory or to disk to prevent having to recreate images.

Here is how my FileProvider middleware is setup

```
app.UseStaticCustomFiles(new StaticCustomFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new ImageProvider("app root", imageProcessor),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/images"),
});
```

I can set the `OnPrepareResponse` property setting the cache control values like so

```
app.UseStaticCustomFiles(new StaticCustomFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new ImageProvider("app root", imageProcessor),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/images"),
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        const int durationInSeconds = 3600 * 24 * 15;
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    }
});
```

But I think that is a private cache-control which means it will cache it per request and won't be shared with other apps.

How can I set up the shared cache so if multiple users requested `https://example.com/images/blue_skye.jpg?maxwidth=200` the server would create the images at 200 pixels and cache it for the all future request from any other users/app?

Comment: I think caching to disk makes the most sense. Based on what you said, I would ditch the sense of caching with expiration and just return the scaled image if it exists on disk.  If not, generate the scaled image, save it, then return it.  It will now be there for future use (forever). If there's need to clean up files, you can write any logic that makes sense that will delete old files that are not the original.

Comment: @Jemes If I store the generated file to local disk, then each time a request comes in, I have to execute `File.Exists()`, if exists return it, otherwise create a new file and return it. Would that be considered cheaper operation than having to create the file? I am trying to see if disk caching is work the extra space that it will require.